# minimizing beale function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to minimize Beale function using scipy optimize, it's a function with two variables, using the following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
#define function f(x)
def beale(position):
    return (1.5-position[0]+position[0]*position[1])**2+(2.25-position[0]+position[0]*position[1]**2)**3+(2.2625-position[0]+position[0]*position[1])**3

res =minimize(beale, [-4.5,4.5], method="Nelder-Mead")
print (res)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
 RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  res =optimize.minimize(f, [2, -1], method="Nelder-Mead")
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: sorry for that , i just edited it

Comment: FYI: Your implementation of the Beale function doesn't match the formulas shown at https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/beale.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization.

Answer (score 1):

*"What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?"*

It means that the solver, instead of converging to the minimum, has taken steps that move it to larger coordinate values, where your polynomial expression is so large that it overflows the limits of 64 bit floating point numbers.

If I correct the formula to be the actual Beale function, and if I use a starting point closer to the expected result, the function works.  This script

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def beale(position):
    x, y = position
    return (1.5 - x + x*y)**2 + (2.25 - x + x*y**2)**2 + (2.625 - x + x*y**3)**2


x0 = [1.0, 1.0]
res = minimize(beale, x0, method="Nelder-Mead")
print(res)
```

produces the output

```
 final_simplex: (array([[3.00002489, 0.50000749],
       [2.99993609, 0.49998427],
       [3.00005157, 0.50000776]]), array([1.39263183e-10, 6.54120047e-10, 1.00978644e-09]))
           fun: 1.392631830241483e-10
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 107
           nit: 56
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([3.00002489, 0.50000749])
```

The known exact solution is (3, 0.5).